# Can't import imagegrab

Tags: python, import, python-imaging-library, imagegrab

Hey I wanted to make a bot for the humenbenchmark aim training (https://humanbenchmark.com/tests/aim) but when I try to import imagegrab I get a really long error and I don't know what it means. The error is:

```
  `File "(Path to my python file)", line 1, in <module>
  from PIL import ImageGrab File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 915, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 973, in get_data
  OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`
```

And my code is:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
```

Edit:
I started testing a little bit and figured out that imagegrab isn't the only module giving that error. Numpy and pyautogui doesn't work either but modules like random and time does work.

Comment: are u running from linux? because ImageGrab don't works for linux

Comment: No I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: If you are on Windows 10, use the CMD (Command prompt) to run the script.

Visual Studio Code sometimes has trouble running it directly through itself.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help